# Is there a way to tell if a data mirror has been used?

Tags: hard-drive, mirroring, windows-server-2016

We have a data mirror setup for a drive, I know it was used real-time because I seen it re-syncing and seen the corruption errors first. I was hoping to provide documented proof to management though, and to do that, I need to capture evidence that the mirror was indeed used, does anyone know if, and where this evidence is stored?

Specifically, I'm talking about a mirror volume in Disk Management on a Windows Server 2016 Machine.

Comment: What do you mean with 'has been used'. It is part of the disk array. If you read anything it might have only read from one disk (in case of a poor implementation, usually a mirror reads from both stripes doubling read speed). So on reads it would be used. If you wrote anything to the diskthen it would have been written to all drives in the mirror. So it would have been used. The only way not to use it is to disconnect the disk or by having an improper setup.

Comment: You can't definitively tell this, but you might be able to get some hints from SMART results and log files.